# end loop based on input from user

Tags: c, function, loops, midi

My program accepts a number from the user to determine the length of a sequence being recorded. How would i take that number and also let it determine the number of times this loop is performed. While(true) obviously does not allow the loop to end at all.

thanks in advance

here is the function to synthesise sound from midi input

```
void midisound (int note)
    {
        int velocity;
        int playingNote = -1;
        float frequency;

        while(true)
        {
            note = aserveGetNote();
            velocity = aserveGetVelocity();

            if(velocity > 0)
            {
                frequency = 440 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
                aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
                playingNote = note;
            }
            else if(note == playingNote)
            {
                aserveOscillator(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }

        }


    }

---here is where function ^ is called in the program----

   if (reclayer == 1)
                    {
                        //open first text file for layer 1 to be written to
                        textFilePointer = fopen("recording1.txt", "w+");
                        if(textFilePointer == NULL)
                        {
                            printf("Error Opening File!");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            //function call to write notes and vel data
                            notetofile(input, seqlen, reclayer);
                            printf("Would you like to record a second layer or re-record? (y or n)\n");
                            scanf(" %c", &choice2);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: use one variable and initialize that into zero. then increment that for every loop. Using that you can get the no.of times that loop is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop.

```
for ( i = 0; i < note; i++ ) {
    // Your code here
}
```

This will execute 'note' number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the `scanf()` function to input a user number from the console:

```
void midisound (int note) {
    int input;
    int velocity;
    int playingNote = -1;
    float frequency;

    printf("Enter integer number of times to loop: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    while(input > 0) {
        input = input - 1;
        note = aserveGetNote();
        velocity = aserveGetVelocity();

        if(velocity > 0) {
            frequency = 440 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
            aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
            playingNote = note;

        } else if(note == playingNote) {
            aserveOscillator(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that first get the number input from the user number of time loop will be run the use following

for ( i=0 ; i < max ; i++ )

Answer (score 0):

First assign a variable which holds the number of times you want to repeat it. For example , let us take `int n = 5;`. ( You can also make the user input the value of `n` ( as that is what you have asked ) by calling `scanf( "%d " , &n );` and then do the rest )

```
int n ;
scanf( "%d " , &n );
```

You can use this as common for all of my below cases

Then, just add a simple for loop, such as

```
int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
  {
     // The code that you want to repeat
  }
```

That should do the trick.

In case you want to use a while loop, then as before, let `n` be the number of times the loop must execute. Then

```
int i=0;
while ( i < n )
  {
     // Your code
     i++;
  }
```

You can also use the `while ( true )` loop as well, but you will just have to give a condition and use `break;`. Let us take an example as above.

```
int i=0;
while ( true )
  {
     // your code
     i++;
     if ( i == n )
        break;
  }
```

These are just many of the different possibilities. You can even come up with your own condition if you try.

Happy coding .... 8-)